# Override Bulma Variables in Nuxt Component

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, bulma, nuxt.js

I try to change the Value of `$navbar-height` via a mounted function in a Nuxt component.
Everything is working so far except overriding Bulma Variables

I added Bulma in the Nuxt config:

```
modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc:https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/tree/master/packages/bulma
    '@nuxtjs/bulma',
    '@nuxtjs/font-awesome'
  ]
```

And changed some Variables in my `main.scss` file:

```
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables';
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/mixins';
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/functions';

$primary: #3dccc8;
$danger: #dc5222;
$navbar-height: 5rem;
$navbar-item-img-max-height: 3rem;

@import '~bulma/bulma';
```

The `main.scss` also got added to the Nuxt Config

```
css: [
    { src: '~assets/css/main.scss', lang: 'scss' }
  ],
```

I now try to manipulate the Variable in a component, but nothing happens.

Here is the function:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function(){
      window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        var navbar = document.getElementById("nav")
        var nav_classes = navbar.classList
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 10) {
          if (nav_classes.contains("shrink") === false) {
            nav_classes.toggle("shrink");
            console.log(nav_classes)
          }
        }
        else {
          if (nav_classes.contains("shrink") === true) {
            nav_classes.toggle("shrink");
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: you can't overwrite sass variables in javascript runtime since the sass is compiled to css

Comment: Any other solution then?

Answer (score 7):

you can comment out `@nuxtjs/bulma` from your `nuxt.config.js` file, import `main.scss` where you could have:

```
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables'; 
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/functions';

// customize styles

$black: #343434; 
$family-sans-serif: Avenir, sans-serif;

@import '~bulma';
```

So no need to uninstall nuxt-bulma and reinstall the regular one.

Answer (score 4):

In order to customize bulma you should not use `@nuxtjs/bulma`.This package adds the standard prebuilt bulma css.

The solution is to build bulma within your project.

First, install node-sass and sass-loader packages
`npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev`

Then add the following entry to nuxt.config.js: 
`css: [{src: '@/assets/sass/app.sass', lang: 'sass' }],`

In `assets/sass/app.sass`, you put the following

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all"; // -- (1)
$navbar-height: 40px // you can customize the variable here
@import "~bulma"; // then you load bulma
```

The line (1) is optional, but you will probably need it to load utility functions that help you calculating the variables you want to customize.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020**

I took the SCSS file from https://buefy.org/documentation/customization/.

```
// Import Bulma's core
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";

// Set your colors
$primary: #8c67ef;
$primary-light: findLightColor($primary);
$primary-dark: findDarkColor($primary);
$primary-invert: findColorInvert($primary);

// There are more other styles and variables here.

// Import Bulma and Buefy styles
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

Then I added it in the assets folder with name `style.scss` you can choose your own name.

Update variables and styles based on your preference.

After that I installed sass-loader.

```
yarn add node-sass sass-loader -D
```

I added my created scss file in the `default.vue`

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '~assets/style.scss';
</style>
```

*Re-run to reflect the changes.